# Can't figure out backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Sorry if this is a super-noob question but I am desperately trying to learn Backbone.js for a job and I have spent the whole week reading and watching videos on codeschool.com and I still can't figure this out.

I am trying to render a json file as a table in a template but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and every time I try something I do worse and worse.

Here is my JS:

```
        Game = Backbone.Model.extend({});

        Games = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Game
        })

        window.AllGames = new Games();

        AllGames.fetch({
            url: 'games_in_progress.json'
            , success: function() {
            //console.log(AllGames.toJSON());
            }
        });

        GameList = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: 'body',
            listTemplate: _.template($('#game_list').html(), {}),
            initialize: function(){
               //this.render();
                this.collection = new AllGames();
                this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
                this.collection.fetch();
            },
            render: function(){
                //var listTemplate = _.template($('#game_list').html(), {});
                //this.$el.html(listTemplate);
                console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
                $(this.el).html(this.listTemplate(this.collection.toJSON()));
            }
        });

        var gameList = new GameList({
            el:$(".content")
        });
```

Here is the json file I'm trying to import:

```
{
"title": "Tic Tac Toe Games in Progress",
"games": [
    {"id": 1, "player1": "Eric Morgan", "player2": "Charles May", "player1_wins": 0, "player2_wins": 2},
    {"id": 2, "player1": "Valerie Bowman", "player2": "Felicia Cole", "player1_wins": 0, "player2_wins": 0},
    {"id": 3, "player1": "Guy Benson", "player2": "Norman Day", "player1_wins": 3, "player2_wins": 3},
    {"id": 4, "player1": "Emanuel Weaver", "player2": "Sammy Nelson", "player1_wins": 10, "player2_wins": 4},
    {"id": 5, "player1": "Oliver Mcbride", "player2": "Jill Hansen", "player1_wins": 102, "player2_wins": 30},
    {"id": 6, "player1": "Alison Bell", "player2": "Owen Dixon", "player1_wins": 10, "player2_wins": 200},
    {"id": 7, "player1": "Lawrence Adams", "player2": "Ebony Schmidt", "player1_wins": 1, "player2_wins": 0},
    {"id": 8, "player1": "Tony Robbins", "player2": "Shelley Mills", "player1_wins": 5, "player2_wins": 21},
    {"id": 9, "player1": "Dustin Watts", "player2": "Glen Clayton", "player1_wins": 12, "player2_wins": 19},
    {"id": 10, "player1": "Douglas Bates", "player2": "Eduardo Martin", "player1_wins": 1, "player2_wins": 3},
    {"id": 11, "player1": "Lola Swanson", "player2": "Nichole Carlson", "player1_wins": 101, "player2_wins": 0},
    {"id": 12, "player1": "Fernando Mitchell", "player2": "Bessie Sharp", "player1_wins": 9, "player2_wins": 0},
    {"id": 13, "player1": "Randal Austin", "player2": "Rodolfo Mccormick", "player1_wins": 7, "player2_wins": 90},
    {"id": 14, "player1": "Louise Chandler", "player2": "Laura Beck", "player1_wins": 93, "player2_wins": 112},
    {"id": 15, "player1": "Ernesto Brock", "player2": "Lois Singleton", "player1_wins": 109, "player2_wins": 87},
    {"id": 16, "player1": "Lora Osborne", "player2": "Katie Johnston", "player1_wins": 201, "player2_wins": 7},
    {"id": 17, "player1": "Priscilla Horton", "player2": "Julius Hale", "player1_wins": 10, "player2_wins": 53},
    {"id": 18, "player1": "Andrew Fernandez", "player2": "Henrietta Morris", "player1_wins": 30, "player2_wins": 99},
    {"id": 19, "player1": "Joe Shelton", "player2": "Martin Ramsey", "player1_wins": 34, "player2_wins": 20},
    {"id": 20, "player1": "Mary Little", "player2": "Pam Goodwin", "player1_wins": 29, "player2_wins": 43},
    {"id": 21, "player1": "Lynda Nguyen", "player2": "Jermaine Hughes", "player1_wins": 61, "player2_wins": 71},
    {"id": 22, "player1": "Clifford Young", "player2": "Tonya Baldwin", "player1_wins": 0, "player2_wins": 0},
    {"id": 23, "player1": "Adrienne Kennedy", "player2": "Jordan Howard", "player1_wins": 10, "player2_wins": 1},
    {"id": 24, "player1": "Lena Newton", "player2": "Kristi Guerrero", "player1_wins": 30, "player2_wins": 1},
    {"id": 25, "player1": "Alicia Casey", "player2": "Jody Lopez", "player1_wins": 0, "player2_wins": 0}
]
}
```

I know it's bad, but I actually like Backbone and I really want to learn it. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Also, if there are any recommended books to read, I would also appreciate it. I am currently reading "Backbone Tutorials" by Thomas Davis (https://leanpub.com/backbonetutorials) but if there are any better resources than this or codeschool.com I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my browser cut off half the window:

Please note that when defining the template function you are already compiling it by providing an empty object,
therefore you need to skip the empty object assignment in the definition.

Correct way would be like this : 
`listTemplate: _.template($('#game_list').html()),`

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you have any resources that could recommend me to read since I am completely lost. How did you learn Backbone?